# My loop with try catch is stuck in endless loop and it should prompt the user each time for an input

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch

I'm trying to ask the user for a number and if they enter anything wrong (not an int between 1 and 99) then catch (to prevent crash if string) and loop until enter a right number. My loop is stuck in an endless loop somehow. Note: I do have the Scanner imported and the exception imported too.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String result;
        int number;
        boolean done = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Please select a number from 1 to 99.");
                number = input.nextInt();
                input.nextLine();

                if (number >= 1 || number <= 99) {
                    result = checkNumber(number);
                    System.out.println(result);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `input.nextInt()` won't consume anything not an `int`. It will throw an exception. You ignore the exception and try to consume an `int`. It's still not an `int`. Same exception. Infinite loop. Add another `input.nextLine()` in your `catch` block.

Comment: Wow. such an easy fix. Thank you so much! I think you helped me on my last question too the other day!! Many thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input.nextInt()` won't consume anything not an `int`. It will throw an exception. You ignore the exception and try to consume an `int`. It's still not an `int`. Same exception. Infinite loop. Add another `input.nextLine()` in your catch block.